# Problems with speeding up mediaplayer and using setNextMediaPlayer() function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem speeding up my MediaPlyer(). It should play a sequence of files,and because of the gap in playing I used setNextMediaPlayer() function and prepared with player1 my next song. Now I decided to let the user pick the speed in which a player should play all the sounds, but when I use `player.setPlaybackParams` only for `player` i don't get the result I want,and when I use it for `player1` too, app crashes.

This is my code for function play:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void play(View v) throws InterruptedException {
        for(i=0;i<brojac;i++)
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this,this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i).toString(),"raw",getPackageName()));
            float speed = Float.parseFloat((String) textview.getText());
            if(i==0) {
                player.setPlaybackParams(player.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
            }
            if(i!=brojac-1) {
                player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i + 1).toString(), "raw", getPackageName()));
                player1.setPlaybackParams(player1.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
                player.setNextMediaPlayer(player1);
            }
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    mp=null;
                }
            });
            if(player1!=null) {
                player1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;
                    }
                });
            }
            player.start();
            Thread.sleep((long) (player.getDuration()));
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

My LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(Native Method)
        at com.lisstudio.songmaker.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.java:115)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some researching and trying out,I've found the solution.
Firstly, it is important to be careful about Thread.sleep method because you need to pass duration of the song including speed change, so player.getDuration()/speed.
And secondly, you need to put speed on player only, and not player1.

Here it is:

```
for(i=0;i<brojac;i++)
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this,this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i).toString(),"raw",getPackageName()));
            float speed = Float.parseFloat((String) textview.getText());
            player.setAudioAttributes();

                player.setPlaybackParams(player.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));

            if(i!=brojac-1) {
                player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, this.getResources().getIdentifier(lista.get(i + 1).toString(), "raw", getPackageName()));

            }

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.release();
                    player=null;
                }
            });
            if(player1!=null) {
                player1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (player != null) {
                            player.setNextMediaPlayer(player1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if(player1!=null) {
                player1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        player1.release();
                        player1 = null;
                    }
                });
            }
            player.start();
            Thread.sleep((long) (player.getDuration()/speed));
        }
```